# Are security staff of foreign ambassadors allowed to carry firearms in countries such as UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, policy

Let's consider the UK, where most police officers do not carry firearms.

> Authorised Firearms Officers (AFOs) may only carry firearms when
>   authorised by an "appropriate authorising officer".

Are the security staff of, let's say, the US Ambassador in the UK allowed to carry firearms beyond the premises of the US embassy and discharge the weapon (potentially public places, if there is a threat)?

Comment: As currently written, this is actually quite a lot of different questions, mostly about firearms laws in the UK, rather than policy or politics. It might be more suited to the Law Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @origimbo In Britain, even if you have a licensed firearm (which doesn't apply in the case of any handgun, as they are completely outlawed, other than for police and military) you are certainly not allowed to carry it on your person around any urban area. The only licenses that are given are for sporting rifles and shotguns (used in the country). And anything above a very low calibre has to be kept under strict lock and key on the premises of a licensed gun club

Comment: I think - only inside the embassy. But the Metropolitan police have an armed "diplomatic protection squad", to protect foreign embassies, diplomats, and other sensitive people etc.- such as the royal family and their residences. Scotland Yard may have individual arrangements with embassies. During tensions in specific countries e.g.in the Middle East, it is not unusual to see an armed officer posted on their embassy's front door. The really sensitive embassies, such as the Russian and Israeli are in Kensington Palace Gardens, which I believe has police barriers at either end.

Answer (score 5):

One UK tabloid newspaper suggests so, but for heads of state, not mere ambassadors.

[Foreign VIP bodyguards 'carry guns'](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/foreign-vip-bodyguards-carry-guns-246626)

> Commander Bob Broadhurst said: "The request is always asked and nearly always declined. Occasionally, with the US, there are a number allowed - one or two close officers - to carry a firearm."

It seems that only the close protection staff of visiting heads of state are able to negotiate the issuing of temporary firearms licences (or equivalent permission). Guards who are not accredited diplomatic staff do not have immunity from UK law.

Comment: One amusing anecdote I heard concerned Reagan's visit to stay at Chequers with MT. The US Security boys were checking the arrangements the previous week and noted a public footpath that went within about 30 feet of the front window. "Can we block this path off?" asked one of the US guys to the senior police officer supervising. "Afraid not. That's a Public Right of Way. And you can only change that with an Act of Parliament. And you won't get one of those by next week. Besides this is Buckinghamshire!"

Answer (score -1):

UK firearms laws are irrelevant.

Diplomats have immunity under the Vienna Convention which covers their cars, designated diplomatic bags and premises of the mission. They are also immune from search and cannot be prosecuted. Case in point the murder of British police officer Yvonne Fletcher outside the Libyan embassy in 1979.

The Libyan diplomat involved was not prosecuted.

Why do diplomats have immunity? Because we need it do our jobs. For example, most diplomats do fairly routine jobs, like issuing and refusing visas. We need to be able to issue and refuse visas, taking only into consideration the national interest of our home country. As a diplomat in a foreign mission, If I refuse a visa I need to be certain I am not going to get sued/prosecuted by the applicant for the cost of their lost airfare in their own country because I refused them entry to mine.

It makes sense and this is why we have immunity. In addition, sometimes diplomats work in difficult, dangerous and unstable countries where carrying firearms is fairly routine.

If dips abuse their immunity, their embassy can waive their immunity. However, some, especially developing/very corrupt countries, don't give a shit making diplomats from some countries extremely dangerous, or sometimes the mission (usually consulates) only contains the consul themselves and nobody else.

Case in point, someone I know paid a diplomat from a tiny African country to beat the shit out of a Chinese hacker who was running online casinos in Shanghai many years ago on behalf of the European gambling operators that he stole from. The police arrested the African diplomat, and he waived his dip passport at them. In this case, they may still detain (although in theory they're not even supposed to do this; most cops have never met this situation and mistakenly do/try anyway and get in very serious shit further down the line), but cannot search. They then need to obtain a 'waiver of diplomatic immunity' in order to prosecute. In order to get this, they rang and rang the phone number of his tiny country's consulate in Shanghai but basically he was the only person working in the consulate so the phone just rang and rang as he was in jail. When they released him they rang the consulate again the next day and he picked up the phone and told the police to fuck off.

In reality, host countries of course don't like the idea of dips wondering around packing heat. They often tell diplomats they cannot carry guns but the fact of the matter is, they are powerless to prevent them from doing so.

A country can't prosecute a diplomat from another state, only to declare them to be persona non grata, and demand that they leave the country, but no other action can be taken against them.

If diplomats start popping off shots the police or army can engage, but not arrest. Though technically it's a military matter, not a police one. Hence why the UK gov. sent the SAS and not the police to deal with the Iranian embassy siege.

In practice, though most diplomats don't carry guns.

Source - I am a former UK diplomat.